# How to get product info tabbed section in other place?

Tags: magento-1.9, products

I want to display product info tabbed section side to product image but not on bottom how can I do this.Can someone help me in doing this.

[image]

**UPDATE:** I got tabbed sections beside my product image with the help of dh47 and now as in the image my product name and price should be inside description tab which is now outside the tabs I tried to copy this code from `view.phtml` and tried to paste it in `description.phtml`  but the all my tabs  getting removed.Please help me in doing this.

```
            <div class="product-name">
                <span class="h1"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="price-info">
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: iam using  RWD theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `catalog.xml` file and search for this code

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
                </block>
```

this is the code which give you information in tabbed section.

I have noticed you need to add extra tabs as per your requirement so

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                        <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                        <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Info &amp; Care</value></action>
                    </block>
```

add in this way for extra tabs don't forget to create .phtml pages regarding to your tabs description.

now to change position of your tabbed section got `view.phtml` page and find for this code.

```
 <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

copy it and paste it after this `<div class="price-info">` then you can get your required output.